# Ruby on rails toggle the mark as complete button value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I am working on a rails project.
In that I have a Mark as complete button,i just want to toggle its value and save the new value in the database,every time someone clicks on it.

Here is my code,but it's not working.

/*modal.html.erb*/

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">

                    <%=form_for subtask,:method => :put,:remote => :true do |f| %>
                    <%=f.hidden_field :name%>
                    <%=f.hidden_field :description%>
                    <%=f.hidden_field :start_date%>
                    <%=f.hidden_field :end_date%>
                    <%=f.hidden_field :task_id%>
                    <%=f.hidden_field :complete%>
                    <%=f.submit 'Mark As Complete',class:'btn btn-success'%>
                    <%end%>

                </div>
```

/*subtask controller*/

```
def update

        @subtask=Subtask.find(params[:id])
        #@task=@subtask.task
        #@subtask.description=params[:subtask][:description]
        respond_to do |format|

                params[:subtask][:complete]=@subtask.toggle(params[:subtask][:complete])
            if @subtask.update_attributes(params[:subtask])
                format.html{redirect_to @project}
                format.js
            else
                render new
            end
        end


    end
```

Can someone please help me in achieving this functionality.

Here is my solution

```
<div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">

                    <%=form_for subtask,:method => :put,:remote => :true do |f| %>
                    <%=f.hidden_field :name%>
                    <%=f.hidden_field :description%>
                    <%=f.hidden_field :start_date%>
                    <%=f.hidden_field :end_date%>
                    <%=f.hidden_field :task_id%>
                    <%=f.hidden_field :complete,:value=>subtask.toggle(:complete).complete%>
                    <%=f.submit 'Mark As Complete',class:'btn btn-success'%>
                    <%end%>

                </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to toggle the attribute asynchronously (e.g. via AJAX without refreshing the page)? Your view code would just produce a button saying "Mark As Complete".

Comment: yes that would happen asynchronously

Comment: This form is on a modal,so when someone click on this button,the value will get saved async and the color of the button will change

Comment: OK. In your view where you have `form_for subtask`, is that variable set correctly? Where does it come from?

Comment: Yes that is correct,I have many subtasks,so that is correct.That page is rendered several times for the subtasks.So in here this subtask is passed to this page.

Comment: Does anything happen? Can you post your logs of what happens when you click the button?

Comment: The data from the form is getting posted properly,I checked it in my network tab of chrome.So till all is working fine.When it goes to the controller,its may be not able to toggle the value.This is the error that I got.undefined method `f?' for #<Subtask:0x56663e8>

Comment: What is the full error log? It should point you to a line number in your code.

Comment: app/controllers/subtasks_controller.rb:40:in `block in update'app/controllers/subtasks_controller.rb:37:in `update'

Comment: this line is the toggle function line

Comment: I replaced that toggle line 40 with this code now params[:subtask][:complete]=@subtask.toggle(:complete).So now I have no error's but still the value in the database is still the same.

Comment: Ok,I have solved this problem.I will edit my solution.Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Sorry that aint working properly,it toggle's the value only for the first time,next time if i press again,toggle does'nt change the value.